# Connecting to PostgreSQL through proxy

Tags: c#, database, winforms, npgsql

I use in my C# Winform project `PostgreSQL` via `Npgsql`. I connect my app to PostgreSQL using the below connection string:

```
 String connstring = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};" +
                    "User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};",
                    "192.168.22.1", "5432", "postgres",
                    "password", "test" );
```

I would like to ask, If I should to pass through xxx.xxx.xxx.xx proxy IP before reaching the DB, what the connection string form would be ?

Comment: What kind of proxy? If it's a plain IP forward, you'd just use its IP and port instead of the real server's. Otherwise: Do you want to use a SOCKS4 or SOCKS5 proxy? A HTTP proxy with `CONNECT` support? Something else?